# 2011 iMac (high-end) taken apart, how to reassemble?

Tags: imac, hardware

Well, this is awkward.

I set about disassembling my iMac in attempt to fix a problem, and the problem is fixed, but now I'm not quite sure how to put it back together.

Does anyone know where I can find a guide on how to put it back together?

Do you think Apple repairs (store & authorized dealers) will take my iMac and put it back together if I asked them to? (Out of my pocket of course, my warranty expired)

[image: This is awkward]

[image: Optic Drive, Hard Drive, power boards]

[image: Logic Board]

Comment: Nice house plans. Is that a 3 bedroom? In the future, try taking the pictures as you disassemble your computer. Closest manual I can come up with is for a [iMac mid 2010](http://www.tim.id.au/blog/tims-laptop-service-manuals/).

Comment: haha its a warehouse

Answer (score 4):

Nothing is better than iFixit [replacement guides](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/iMac_Intel_27%22_EMC_2429) (link for your 27 inch 2011 model). This tutorials are technically correct and safe to apply. Hi-res pictures are also available. Additonally you can try to find some videos in Youtube